# How to highlight text from URL parameters in component Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

i have a component that loads an list from my backend api

```
getSearchResult(): void {
    this.procedimentoService.getSearchResult(this.setUrlParams())
        .then(result => {
            this.ready();
            this.procedimentos = result.procedimentos;
            this.pagination = result.pagination;
        }).then(result => console.log(this.pagination));
}  

setUrlParams(): URLSearchParams {
    this.standby();
    let searchOptions = new URLSearchParams();
    if (this.searchParams){
        for (let key in this.searchParams) {
            if(this.searchParams[key]){
                searchOptions.set(key, this.searchParams[key].toString());
                this.searchParams.page = 1;
            }
        }         
    }
    return searchOptions;                
}
```

So, `getSearchResult()` retrieve my data and set my **url** parameters.

`setUrlParams()` verify if my `[(ngModel)]` has some value, if so, he puts it in my URL as parameters.

Here's what I need: I need to get this text I just typed in my inputs and highlight them in the **columns** of my `grid`.

Sorry about my broken english, hope you guys can understand.

Comment: I actually found something from an old angular build https://plnkr.co/edit/vEZNtbWgCN2Eh969iv7s?p=preview

Comment: Just use [mark.js](https://markjs.io/)?